# Unknown Crashes happened in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am new in spriteKit and am developing a game. I had some memory problem, which I solved, but after playing the game several times it now crashes due to 'bad access'.

At the end of each level I present an Image to indicate whether the user wins or loses, and remove all SKSpriteNodes in the SkScene:

```
[node removeFromParent];
```

and I do not use Preloading for textureAtlas.

This link is from my Xcode:

[image: my Error Image 1]

[image: My Error Image 2]

Crash Log:

[Crash Log Description](http://i60.tinypic.com/2lapkyd.png)

i found the Error using test flight

3   UIKit   0x30ee700c  _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions
4   UIKit   0x30d92502  -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:]
5   UIKit   0x31139af4  ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke

Comment: possibly related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399278/sprite-kit-ios-7-1-crash-on-removefromparent

Comment: @LearnCocos2D 
may be but can you tell me how to solve it ?
i do not know anything about SKNodeShape and i do not use it

Comment: Try adding an exception breakpoint to pinpoint which line causes this error

Comment: Also, a call stack should be logged when this error occurs. Please post that as well.

Comment: @akashg i already post the stack when error occurs in the two images in the question 
my Error Image 1

My Error Image 2

Comment: The stack needs to be symbolicated. The images you have posted cannot be understood

Comment: Let the game crash completely, and then the symbolicated stack should be logged in the debugger.

Comment: @akashg 
i am sorry but can i make it in the development mode after the app is completely crashed how can i get the symbolicated stack in development mode ?

Comment: @akashg i understand you wait a min i will post it

Comment: @akashg it happened in Device only how can i get the symbolicated stack log

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375851/iphone-how-to-symbolicate-translate-read-device-crashlog-with-xcode-4

Comment: @akashg i post the stack log

Comment: This does not look like the crash log for your app. Have you tried setting an exception breakpoint?

Comment: @akashg i made archive and put it on my ipad then get what is written in console is this right ?

Comment: @akashg i upload the Crash log can you kindly check it

Comment: This is the correct crash log, but like I said, this needs to be symbolicated.

Comment: ok, so you are using a UIGestureRecognizer in your app?

Comment: @akashg yes i am yes gesture Recogniser in Skcenes but it 's crash in other sKcene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot understand your crash log, you can debug this while running your app itself at runtime.

A simple way to prevent `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` can be:

```
if (node != nil)
{
    [node removeFromParent];
}
```

Comment: i think send Message to nil object does not crash the app

Comment: You still have not been able to point out where exactly you get this crash

Comment: can you check Crash log description Link in the Question

Comment: "I think" is not valid, unless you have actually tried it out. The Crash Log link is not Symbolicated. Check this: http://kevincupp.com/2011/05/12/symbolicating-ios-crash-logs.html

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS usually means that you are sending a message to an object that no longer exists.

Comment: i get .ips file in the crash report folder not .crash file do you have any idea about how to symobolicate it and also i have .ipa file and .dsym file

Comment: @akashg I know that sending messages to nil will not cause a crash.  By the objective -c specification it is a perfectly valid thing to do.  Sending it to nil is very different than sending it to an object that no longer exists.